# How can I get the type System.Windows.Controls.Primitive.PopupRoot?

Tags: wpf, reflection

Pictures can tell a thousand words.

When I climb up the visual tree I see the last parent is of type System.Windows.Controls.Pimitives.PopupRoot
[image]

But Whey I try to actually make a comparison to that type VS complains it's not valid.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`PopupRoot` is `internal` to `PresentationFramework`, so you cannot access it from your assembly. You can compare the type name with `GetType().FullName`, but `PopupRoot` is an implementation detail that can change in future framework versions so I wouldn't rely on it.

Comment: All of which tells me I need a more generic solution.

Answer (score 6):

`PopupRoot` is internal, so you will not be able to reference it. However, if you use `LogicalTreeHelper`, you'll be able to find `Popup` if exists. `LogicalTreeHelper` will return NULL if there is no logical parent, so you need to use it in addition to walking visual tree with `VisualTreeHelper`.

Here is an example how you can use it:

```
var popupRootFinder = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent((DependencyObject)your_visual_element);
while (popupRootFinder != null)
{
    var logicalRoot = LogicalTreeHelper.GetParent(popupRootFinder);
    if (logicalRoot is Popup)
    {
        // popup root found here
        break;
    }

    popupRootFinder = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(popupRootFinder);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get a Popup object from PopupRoot then you can do it with this code where "d" is type PopupRoot:

```
Popup customPopup = LogicalTreeHelper.GetParent(d) as Popup;
```